# from pylab import * fails on RHEL 6 due to need for GLIBC 2.14

Tags: enthought

How might I get a pylab import that works... I'm willing to recompile for my box, but need to know where to put everything this works for all the users. Note that GLIB2.14 is required by libpng16.so.16, which was the original "trip-up" point.  But, I found a version of that, and am now stuck here.  Here's the error:

```
In [2]:

from pylab import *

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-de1a8241b951> in <module>()
----> 1 from pylab import *

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.pylab import *
      2 import matplotlib.pylab
      3 __doc__ = matplotlib.pylab.__doc__

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py in <module>()
    224 # make mpl.finance module available for backwards compatability, in case folks
    225 # using pylab interface depended on not having to import it
--> 226 import matplotlib.finance
    227 
    228 from matplotlib.dates import date2num, num2date,\

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/finance.py in <module>()
     21 from matplotlib.dates import date2num
     22 from matplotlib.cbook import iterable, mkdirs
---> 23 from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PolyCollection
     24 from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
     25 from matplotlib.lines import Line2D, TICKLEFT, TICKRIGHT

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in <module>()
     21 import matplotlib.artist as artist
     22 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 23 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
     24 import matplotlib.path as mpath
     25 from matplotlib import _path

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in <module>()
     48 
     49 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 50 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
     51 from matplotlib.path import Path
     52 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py in <module>()
      9 from matplotlib.path import Path
     10 from matplotlib import rcParams
---> 11 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     12 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
     13 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT

/users/p/c/pclemins/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     51 import matplotlib
     52 from matplotlib import afm
---> 53 from matplotlib import ft2font
     54 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_cachedir
     55 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like

ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/libpng16.so.16)
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, you installed a wrong version of libpng16, perhaps from an rpm or compiled for a different system, not the OS you are using.

The canopy package manager has the correct version of libpng available, if you install that things should work fine. You can install it from the canopy package manager gui or via the `enpkg libpng` command. (Unfortunately it appears libpng is missing from default canopy install whereas it should have been included.)